# flutter/firebase_messaging - "Notifications are not allowed for this application" - how fix it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos, push-notification

I have flutter app. It is working for iOS. now I try to run it on macos - I have problems:

1. I added GoogleService-Info.plist to my macos/runner
2. my app uses firebase_messaging(for push notification)

   ```
   final settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
   announcement: true,
   carPlay: true,
   sound: true,
   criticalAlert: true,
   );
   ```

this code returns an error:

```
 [firebase_messaging/unknown] Notifications are not allowed for this application
```

Found this [discussion](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/5473)

here they advise you to manually add permissions for your application, via System Preferences > Notifications

but I don't see my app there. i installed it via TestFlight - but that didn't help either, the app is not listed.

how do i solve this problem? any advice - I will be grateful

also i don't know how to configure my app properly. I found this [document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/macos/) but there are no details (what permissions are needed and other details)

Comment: Hi Fet, I just want to ask a simple question, if your Xcode - IOS configuration is correct? did you enable Push notifications and Background refresh? also, did you specify the needed strings in the info.plist?

Comment: @RamiAlDebs I'm not sure if I've set it up correctly.
"Push notifications" - I enabled 
"Background refresh" - I have not found how to enable this option,
info.plist - what should i add here?
I only found this document but it doesn't have these details - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/macos/

Comment: follow every step in here https://medium.com/@m1nori/ios-setup-of-push-notifications-flutter-firebase-775b0430140e

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Messaging currently does not support macOS.

To implement push notifications for macOS, you must use the Apple Push Notification service directly. However, you are to write platform-specific code for macOS.

Comment: Is it true? I found this documentation - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/macos/